# Good Source Of .Net Design Patterns

Tags: .net, design-patterns, resources

I'm looking for a good online resource of software patterns. Preferably something with a comprehensive selection and concise well written explanations, not just a collection of links. .Net examples would be nice, but not essential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see real world examples of patterns implemented, why not grab an open source .net project such as Paint.NET or CommunityServer and have a look through the codebase? You could also get Reflector and have a look at the source code for the base class library.

Comment: @WillVousden; It was when this answer was posted.

Comment: However, unlike most proprietary software licenses, the new license allows users to decompile and reverse engineer the software, provided that no modifications are made.

Inserted from <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paint.NET>

Answer (score 8):

[Enterprise Solutions Patterns using Microsoft .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998469.aspx)

[Design Patterns for ASP.NET Programmers](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/33695)

[Data and Object Factory, Inc -- Patterns](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx)

[DesignPatternsFor.Net](http://www.designpatternsfor.net/default.aspx?pid=4)

Answer (score 8):

I recommend [Head First Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124) book from Freemans. These are general design patterns applicable in most OO languages. I recommend this book as an introductory book to design patterns. After this book the [GOF book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612) would be another recommendation (but not as a first book).

Comment: +1 for Head First Design Patterns as a first pattern book

Comment: I totally agree with David, i personally read both books and when i read your question i have same answer in my mind as david

Answer (score 4):

Grab this book:

[P of EEA](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321127420) By Martin Fowler

Here's the online info of that book

http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/

Answer (score 3):

A couple of other resources

- [Gang of Four has some patterns, too.](http://www.dofactory.com/Default.aspx)
- [MSDN Patterns & Practices may also be helpful](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/practices/default.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to read the book .NET Design Patterns.

Some of the books above I have read and can certainly vouch for.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a descriptions of [Design Patterns](http://sourcemaking.com/)

I thing this is a very good page for reading and learning about design patterns