# Is there any good framework or library for c# snips of design-patterns?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

We want to build a library of c# *snips* for .NET.  We are looking around to see if there is something similar out there.  The library will be open source and free to use and distribute.

I see there is a similar question here, but is more theoretical than practical, I want to have [Good Source of .NET Dsg Patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324824/good-source-of-net-design-patterns).  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doodads has a lot of C# examples in their website

[Here is a list of GOF Pattern implementation in C#](http://dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx)

They also have a 'Design Pattern Framework' for GOF patterns, it is commercial. I purchased it long time back, was good for reference.

http://dofactory.com/Framework/Framework.aspx

Answer (score 9):

If there would be a library, why would we even bother with the pattern? We'd just use the lib and fall into the pit of success.

The idea of the pattern is to not make the same mistake as the other thousand developers. The pattern is something of "if you need to architect something that way, this way works best" .. And everybody knows what I'm talking about when saying "strategy, or factory etc"

Correct me if i'm wrong...

Comment: +1 to you. I totally agree. Design pattern are not templates.  They are time tested solutions to common problems.

Comment: I don't think he meant library as in DLL.  I think he meant library as in starter code snippets.

Comment: Then why use "open soruce" and free-to-use in the question? I have never heard of a open-source book (usually I need to have the source available to read it *g*)

Comment: I don't see how this is relevant to the question. He's talking about bundling a bunch of C# snippets for redistribution, not a magical master library.

Comment: I did not know this question will cause so much noise.  Well thanks too all for your comments.  I agree that design templates should be kept as theory.  We are just trying to make some conventional Snippets for C# coders.  I hope all understand.  And thanks again, all your comments are valuable.

Answer (score 1):

- [Lokad Shared Libraries](http://rabdullin.com/shared-libraries/) - I dislike [Enterprise Library](http://www.codeplex.com/entlib) for the unnecessary complexity and inflexibility, so I'm using these helpers and patterns instead
- [Misc Util](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/) - Misc helpers for .NET
- [NetFX](http://code.google.com/p/netfx/) - Misc helpers for .NET

Comment: +1 - for the good links + the user friendly explanations for each one of them. Thanks !

Comment: links are dead :(