# Suggest a good design and architecture book for .Net development

Tags: .net

Anyone please suggest a good design and architecture book for .Net.

Is there any book I can refer to which has case studies, examples, etc. so that I can update my knowledge well in this field?

In case it's not available for .Net, please suggest in Java also.

Thanks in advance
Swapna MC

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/490807/c-design-patterns-book , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324824 , etc.

Comment: I don't know if it's an exact duplicate, design patterns and architecture patterns are different enough.

Comment: Agreed...there are design patterns, and there is architecture.

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend this book:
[.NET: Architecting Applications for the Enterprise](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/073562609X)

Not a .net book, but the classic book here is 
[Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321127420)

Comment: +1 from me for .NET Architecting Applications for the Enterprise. I'm reading it now and it is pretty good. It is a good companion book for POEAA.

Comment: These two books are the best place to start

Answer (score 3):

Here are some enterprise architecture books that contain case studies. They are not restricted to .Net, since at the architecture level many patterns and practices will apply irrespective of the specific platform choice:

[Simple Architectures for Complex Enterprises
by Roger Sessions](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/books/12649.aspx)

[Event-Driven Architecture: How SOA Enables the Real-Time Enterprise
by Hugh Taylor; Angela Yochem; Les Phillips; Frank Martinez](http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=9780321322111)

[Enterprise Web 2.0 Fundamentals
by Krishna Sankar; Susan A. Bouchard](http://www.ciscopress.com/bookstore/product.asp?isbn=1587057638)

[Beautiful Architecture
Leading Thinkers Reveal the Hidden Beauty in Software Design
By Diomidis Spinellis, Georgios Gousios](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517984/)

[Software Architecture in Practice, Second Edition
by Len Bass; Paul Clements; Rick Kazman](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321154959)

[SOA Design Patterns
by Thomas Erl](http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=9780136135166)

[Modern ESB Architecture for SOA
By: Thomas Erl; Mark Little; Arnaud Simon; Thomas Rischbeck](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/9780137045952)
(Not yet published, expected 10/2009)

[SOA Governance: The key to successful SOA adoption in your organization
by Todd Biske](http://www.packtpub.com/soa-governance/book)
(uses fictional case study)

[Enterprise SOA: Service-Oriented Architecture Best Practices
by Dirk Krafzig; Karl Banke; Dirk Slama](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131465759)

[Applied SOA: SERVICE-ORIENTED ARCHITECTURE AND DESIGN STRATEGIES
by Michael Rosen; Boris Lublinsky; Kevin T. Smith; Marc J. Balcer](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470223650,descCd-authorInfo.html)

Answer (score 2):

A good design book, period, is Martin Fowler's [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321127420). Also a great design book is [Domain-Driven Design: Tackling Complexity in the Heart of Software](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215) by Eric Evans.

Another useful book is [Applying Domain-Driven Design and Patterns: With Examples in C# and .NET](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321268202).

If you are interested in SOA, the true compendium of SOA was written by Thomas Erl:

- [Service-Oriented Architecture: A Field Guide to Integrating XML and Web Services](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131428985)
- [Service-Oriented Architecture (SOA): Concepts, Technology, and Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131858580)
- [SOA Principles of Service Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132344823)
- [Web Service Contract Design and Versioning for SOA](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013613517X)
- [SOA Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0136135161)

And forthcoming:

- [Modern ESB Architecture for SOA](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132360284)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend start by reading the patterns & practices Application Architecture Guide 2.0 http://www.codeplex.com/AppArchGuide

Answer (score 1):

Here's are a few good enterprise architecture books (based on Java, but the general concepts still apply):

- [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321127420)
- [Core J2EE Patterns](http://www.corej2eepatterns.com/) (book or website)

A few of these patterns are a little old, but still useful to know.

If you're interested in WCF for a service-oriented architecture:

- [Programming WCF Services](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596521308)
- [Pro WCF](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590597028)

Or for framework design:

- [Framework Design Guidelines](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321545613)

Answer (score 1):

Architectural approaches can vary greatly depending on what you're trying to build. I.e.- Architecting a specific software's internal's, or architecting a distributed system, etc.

For a given software program's internals, I like [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321127420) as a good reference.

I have also used the [SEDA](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~mdw/proj/seda/) architectural style for some high throughput event-driven applications. The SEDA homepage has the original paper and references to other projects using this style. You might have heard of the Java Open Source projects: MULE and Apache Camel.

Also check out [Enterprise Integration Patterns](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/), which is a great companion book to PoEAA. This one pretty much helps you architect the interconnection between distributed systems. Lots of tools in this area... from XMPP to AMQP, to MULE, to JMS, etc.

And I have to suggest reviewing the [REST Architectural Style](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~mdw/proj/seda/) since it is important in today's web software. There is a lot of material about REST, but primarily read (and reread) Roy Fielding's dissertation.

Answer (score 1):

In general I would see architecture books independent of Java or .NET or any other language. I found this blog post which lists [5 books for an architect](http://www.fromdev.com/2010/08/best-software-architecture-books-must.html).

I hope you would find it interesting too.

Answer (score 0):

I enjoyed Head First Design Patterns:

[http://www.amazon.com/First-Design-Patterns-Elisabeth-Freeman/dp/0596007124](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124)

More design than architecture (obviously) but it makes heavy use of examples.  Examples are in Java, btw.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a book but NDepend documentation comes with some pretty cool online blog posts, articles and white books concerning architecture of .NET code:

[Advices on partitioning code through .NET assemblies](http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2008/12/08/advices-on-partitioning-code-through-net-assemblies.aspx)

[Control Components Dependencies to gain Clean Architecture](http://www.theserverside.net/tt/articles/showarticle.tss?id=ControllingDependencies)

[Re-factoring, Re-Structuring and the cost of Levelizing](http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2009/02/15/re-factoring-re-structuring-and-the-cost-of-levelizing.aspx)

[Evolutionary Design and Acyclic componentization](http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2009/02/22/evolutionary-design-and-acyclic-componentization.aspx)

[Layering, the Level metric and the Discourse of Method](http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2008/02/10/layering-the-level-metric-and-the-discourse-of-method.aspx)

[Fighting Fabricated Complexity](http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2009/06/28/fighting-fabricated-complexity.aspx)

Answer (score -2):

[Head First Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124).